# jQuery Mixed Content

Tags: jquery, http, https

I've received this error on my webpage:

Mixed Content: The page at '...' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I've chanced the path: **https**://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js like in here https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries?hl=tr#jquery But nothing worked.

The code work fine in VS and localhost but when I uploaded my website root I get this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Check the *rendered* HTML on the server - not what you've uploaded, what is actually being sent.  Last time this happened, the user was downloading a *cached* version.   Change something else (eg a version number) to ensure you are serving the correct file.